# cakePHP hasOne relationship not auto completing dropdown field

Tags: cakephp, relationship, has-one

I'm trying to implement a hasone relationship between 2 models, but I can't have the 'add' form autocomplete with the possible options in the second model (the one that *belongsTo* the first one). This is my code:

**- model 1:** item.php

```
<?php
class Item extends AppModel{ 

    var $name = 'Item';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $hasOne = 'CoverImage';
    }
?>
```

**- model 2:** cover_image.php

```
<?php
class CoverImage extends AppModel{ 

    var $name = 'CoverImage';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $belongsTo = array(
                 'Item' => array(
                    'className' => 'Item',
                    'foreignKey' => 'item_id'
                        )); 
}
?>
```

**- add view of model 2:** add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('CoverImage',array('url' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'add')));?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Info'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('item_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Create', true));?>
```

For what I see in Cake's documentation, with this relationship, in the **add** view I should see a dropdown list in the **item_id** field to be able to select to which item does this *CoverImage* belongs to, but the dropdown is empty (and yes, I have some *items* in the items table already).

Maybe I'm missing something or I've done something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thanks so much in advance for any clues!

**EDIT**

One think I've just realized is that if I do this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('item_id', array('type'=>'text'));
```

instead of this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('item_id');
```

I can add/edit the *item_id* field, I can see its value in the text box. However, if I leave the other one, I just see an empty dropbox and when I try to add/edit a *CoverImage*, it doesn't work, it just shows an empty white page, not even with errors...

Maybe this is a lead to something...

Comment: Try:  
`echo $this->Form->inputs();`

It is an automagical way to generate form fields for all attributes, at once.  
It's not a straight answer/solution but maybe it helps you finding clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that to work you have to create a list of possible options in the controller. That does not happen automatically.

```
public function add() {
    $items = $this->CoverImage->Item->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('items'));
}
```

The FormHelper only automatically infers that the field `item_id` should be populated by the options in the variable `$items` (plural, no `_id`).

Do be careful that Items that already *haveOne* CoverImage should not be part of that list. `find('list', array('conditions' => array('CoverItem.id' => null)))` will *probably** take care of that, but you'll need to recheck just before saving as well, or you need to rethink your associations.

* Not sure off the top of my head whether that'll work for `'list'` searches.

Comment: I'm 85% sure that query would actually pull a list of associated CoverImage + Item pairs because the hasOne automatically keys on id. Sure, you could manipulate it to produce the impression you have pulled all available Items for a CoverImage to choose from, which piles a second hack on top of the first. Then, let's say a user chooses an Item which already has a CoverItem. Getting that to save around Item's hasOne would be a third, potentially db-trashing / app-breaking hack. **foreach($compounding as $hack) { $this->answer--** }

Comment: @satyr I'm really not sure what you're saying. `find('list')` will simply get an array of all Items in the form of `array($id => $name)`. You're right that that may conflict with the notion of *"hasOne"* (if that's what you're trying to say), added a note about that.

Comment: I tried and it works! Although I'm not sure what you mean in the second part of your comment (about being careful). I've tried this it also in my **edit** action and seems to be working fine, without using the conditions array in the **find**. Should I use them? Why if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: @Albert Your Items currently *haveOne* CoverImage. That means you can't choose the same Item for two different CoverImages (because then the Item would *haveMany* CoverImages). That's what you need to be careful about or confirm if you really have chosen the right associations.

Comment: In the context of the OP's question. The problem I'm attempting to describe is not that it wouldn't work, but that - in this context - that would be the last thing you'd want to do. Banks hasMany Users, hasMany Accounts. Users belongsTo Banks. Accounts hasOne Users. Because an Account's Bank will be accessible through it's User. **If you're not going to respect the exclusivity of that relationship, such that you find yourself deliberately writing "subduction" finds and dancing around their results, that usually means the real problem is the assigned relationship is not appropriate.**

Answer (score 0):

**EXCELLENT QUESTION.** You've run afoul of a disingenuous feature of Cake's associations:

Considering you defined the relationship as **hasOne**? Guessing at the trace but Cake probably even correctly inferred your preference for list functionality. You got your automagic list...

**...of One.**

$hasOne is pretty exclusive like that. It "uses up" those "has" relationships (it's makes the relationship a de facto Singleton - so Users only have 1 Profile <-> Profile only has 1 User). Consider - Database can have many configurations, but Dbo will only ever have one Connection at a time and Connection will only have one Dbo. Thus -> hasOne is for marrying two Models til die() do they part.

-- So it doesn't get used nearly as much as hasMany and belongsTo.

**For your purpose, you probably want to change to a different association.**

Adding an additional $this->Item->find doesn't really fix what's wrong (and I wouldn't recommend it, unless you're mostly done with both models/controllers, or you actively want things to start getting weird fast.)

Also, changing how you call the Form Helper methods - if you return a 'list' type fetch from a find, Cake will automatically produce an option list out of it. What's actually happening is, you're sneaking around your Model on a very thin margin of View functionality. That's why specifying the input type to "break the magic" tends to be discouraged (which, you totally can if you want. Just understand what's actually happening, or: see, weird, fast.)

But you might want to rethink how you've associated your models - wouldn't it also be correct to say, each Item belongsTo a CoverImage (same as each CoverImage belongs to an Item) -- because you have a form expressly permitting a CoverImage to select an Item, any Item, to be displayed with? You'll probably get better results.

HTH. :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation satyrwilder. Thing is that I don't see the benefit of switching the order of the relationship from **Item->CoverImage** to **CoverImage->Item**, if this is what you mean... I tried the solution that deceze gave, but for what he says and for what you say there might be something bad about doing that, although I can't seem to realize what this is...

Comment: Switching the order wouldn't change anything and unless you included the CoverImage table in Items $uses array, doing so would throw an error. What I mean is, **unless you intend to pull ALL Items and overwrite those that already have a Cover_Id if a new one is selected,** or introduce a filtering step, etc, you will have undesireable results. If you intended to pull all and save over, then congratulations ^_^ If you didn't -- my suggestion was, it's safer and easier to change a $hasOne association than fight it.